# Create a Matrix using different Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have below mentioned four dataframe in R:

```
DF_1

ID      Date
123     18/03/2018 16:45
456     10/03/2018 20:15

DF_2

ID      Date1                  Date2
123     2018-03-18 06:37:22    1519109133704
123     2018-03-18 06:37:21    1520324827462
123     2018-03-16 04:03:01    1520690354458
456     2018-03-10 14:46:03    1517319313151
456     2018-03-10 14:46:04    1515143046429
456     2018-03-10 14:46:03    1515838021062
456     2018-03-10 14:46:15    1488092209241

DF_3

ID      Date1                  Date2
123     2018-03-18 06:37:22    1519109133704
123     2018-03-18 06:37:21    1520324827462
123     2018-03-16 04:03:01    1520690354458
456     2018-03-10 14:46:03    1517319313151
456     2018-03-10 14:46:03    1515838021062
456     2018-03-10 14:46:15    1488092209241

DF_4

ID      Date1                  Date2
123     2018-03-18 06:37:22    1519109133704
123     2018-03-18 06:37:21    1520324827462
456     2018-03-10 14:46:03    1517319313151
456     2018-03-10 14:46:04    1515143046429
```

Using above dataframes i want to create below mentioned matrix:

Output:

```
                         DF_2                               DF_3                    DF_4
ID   Date         Date1  Total  Month Avg Day Last5  Date1  Total  Month Avg Day Last5 Date1  Total  Month Avg   Day Last5
123  18/03/2018
456  10/03/2018
```

Where i below mentioned 6 values w.r.t DF_2, DF_3 and DF_4.

1. Date1 = Considering the `Date` of DF_1 Number of rows for the same date in different dataframe (here we consier `Date1` for all the dataframe (DF_2,DF_3 & DF_4)).
2. Total = Toatl Number of Rows against each `ID` in all other dataframe (i.e DF_2, DF_3 & DF_4)
3. Month = Calculating Number of Month based on `Date2` of all other dataframe (i.e DF_2, DF_3 & DF_4)
4. Avg = Average count of Rows Per Month (Considering `Date2`).
5. Day = Average count of Rows Per Day (Considering `Date2`).
6. Last5 = Count of Rows in Last five days (Considering `Date1` with comparison of current `sys.date()`)

I have a big dataframe so i couldn't use the dput() here, hope it is clearly understood to you guys.

Comment: What code have you tried? Can you simplify your example to be more specific? You might have more luck getting a response.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. You will get better answers if you can make it clearer. I will try to help you out based on what I understood.

- Why do you have dates in 3 different formats. First get all dates to the same format.

  I will show an example with DF_2

  ```
   library(tidyverse)
   library(lubridate)
   DF_2 <- tibble(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 456L), 
                  Date1 = c("2018-03-18 06:37:22", "2018-03-18 06:37:21", "2018-03-16 04:03:01", 
                   "2018-03-10 14:46:03", "2018-03-10 14:46:04", "2018-03-10 14:46:03", 
                   "2018-03-10 14:46:15"), 
                  Date2 = c(1519109133704, 1520324827462, 1520690354458, 1517319313151, 1515143046429, 1515838021062, 1488092209241)
                 )

   DF_2 <- DF_2 %>% mutate(Date1 = ymd_hms(Date1), 
                           Date2 = as.POSIXct(Date2/1000,origin = "1970-01-01")) 

   DF_2_tab <- DF_2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(date1 = sum(date(Date1)==date(DF_1$Date1[DF_1$ID==ID])),
                              Total = n(), 
                              Month = month(which date do you want to use here as you need to get a single number),
                              Day = day(not clear from your description as you need to get a single number for each id as above),
                              Last5 = sum( (Sys.Date()-date(Date1)) < 5 )
                              )
  ```

Now you do the same thing for all your data frames and then use `left_join` to merge all the dataframes by `ID`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In `Month` i want to calculate Number of Month Based on `Date2` and in `Avg` Average Number of Rows Per month (i.e if i have month count 3 and for 90 rows based on `Date2` than my `Avg` would be 30). and `Day` for row created per day like in previous example it would be 1.

Comment: Please help me here.